# Android resource compilation failed - Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my app on android studio it is showing an error like this:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Ravi\AndroidStudioProjects\StudioWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:218: error: invalid color.

Command: C:\Users\Ravi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b6b322bea45b15306011a11f331994cf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Ravi\AndroidStudioProjects\StudioWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \

C:\Users\Ravi\AndroidStudioProjects\StudioWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of values.xml, particularly line 218 which failed?  Also, what is your question? (You only made statements.)

Comment: In Values.xml file the first line is showing two errors                                                                              <resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

Comment: Please help me with this .

Comment: I have deleted the activity_xml

Comment: Is it causing the error

Comment: Please add the values.xml file to your question (there is an "edit" link between the question and comments).  The error message says line 218 is causing the problem, so please be sure to include that line, but preferably all of the values.xml that you are willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

As it is specifying, you have given an invalid color, change the value of the color, maybe it is not in hexadecimal format(Ex. "#DC53FA"). It is just a compilation error.

Colors start from #000000 - Black, #ffffff - White

```
#RGB
#ARGB
#RRGGBB
#AARRGGBB
```

These are the available formats. But the first one is the most common one, for which I have given the example

[Android Studio Documentation -COLORS](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color)

Comment: I have checked the color codes in colors.xml file every thing is seems to be okay just in values.xml file showing two error in first line.                                     urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2                                                                      "http://schemas.android.com/tools

Comment: I have deleted activity_main.xml file . is it causing the error

Comment: Yes, why did you delete the XML file? Are you using some other XML file(with different name maybe), to render?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but for another resource. Maybe it was because I used AndroidX libraries. Anyway try to clean gradle cache, it was successful solution in my case. Just remove directory: **C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches\transforms-1**